# SQL Server: How to convert custom date time string of [yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm] to datetime?

Tags: sql-server

I have a datetime string in `yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm` format eg `2022-08-19T20:25`

I am struggling to find a format to match this in the list of format conversions. https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1145/date-and-time-conversions-using-sql-server/
and keep getting the error: `Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character  string.`

eg.

```
DECLARE @Test DATETIME2 = CONVERT(DATETIME2, '2022-08-19T20:25', 126)
```

Is there a way to pass in a custom format to match?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the seconds. Just append them on:

```sql
DECLARE @Test DATETIME2 = CONVERT(DATETIME2, '2022-08-19T20:25:00', 126);
--or
DECLARE @Test DATETIME2 = CONVERT(DATETIME2, '2022-08-19T20:25' + ':00', 126);
```